# Checking if a bag has enough coins in program

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

The objective of the program is to check that the weight of the bag that the user inputs and then calculate how many coins are needed to the added/removed to ensure the bag has the right amount of coins in. It needs to display the difference in weight and the number of coins to be added/removed and a total value of coins added/removed. The weights can be found within the file.

The bags for 1p and 2p add up to £1. The bags for 5p and 10p add up to £5. The bags for 20p and 50p add up to £10. The bags for 100p and 200p add up to £20.

```
print("Calculation")
print("===========================\n")

one_coin_weight = 3.56
one_bag_amount = 1 / 0.01
one_bag_weight = one_coin_weight * one_bag_amount

two_coin_weight = 7.12
two_bag_amount = 1 / 0.01
two_bag_weight = two_coin_weight * two_bag_amount

five_coin_weight = 3.25
five_bag_amount = 5 / 0.05
five_bag_weight = five_coin_weight * five_bag_amount

ten_coin_weight = 6.50
ten_bag_amount = 5 / 0.10
ten_bag_weight = ten_coin_weight * ten_bag_amount

twenty_coin_weight = 5.00
twenty_bag_amount = 10 / 0.20
twenty_bag_weight = twenty_coin_weight * twenty_bag_amount

fifty_coin_weight = 8.00
fifty_bag_amount = 10 / 0.50
fifty_bag_weight = fifty_coin_weight * fifty_bag_amount

onehundred_coin_weight = 9.50
onehundred_bag_amount = 20 / 1.00
onehundred_bag_weight = onehundred_coin_weight * onehundred_bag_amount

twohundred_coin_weight = 12.00
twohundred_bag_amount = 20 / 2.00
twohundred_bag_weight = twohundred_coin_weight * twohundred_bag_amount

coins_value_added = 0
coins_value_removed = 0

bag_count = int(input("How many bags do you have? "))
print("\n===========================\n")

for x in range(bag_count):
    print("Bag", x + 1, "\n")

    bag_weight = float(input("How much does the bag weigh in grams? "))
    coin_type = int(input("Which type of coin is in the bag in pence? "))

    if coin_type == 1:
        weight_difference = one_bag_weight - bag_weight
        coins_changed = weight_difference / one_coin_weight
    elif coin_type == 2:
        weight_difference = two_bag_weight - bag_weight
        coins_changed = weight_difference / two_coin_weight
    elif coin_type == 5:
        weight_difference = five_bag_weight - bag_weight
        coins_changed = weight_difference / five_coin_weight
    elif coin_type == 10:
        weight_difference = ten_bag_weight - bag_weight
        coins_changed = weight_difference / ten_coin_weight
    elif coin_type == 20:
        weight_difference = twenty_bag_weight - bag_weight
        coins_changed = weight_difference / twenty_coin_weight
    elif coin_type == 50:
        weight_difference = fifty_bag_weight - bag_weight
        coins_changed = weight_difference / fifty_coin_weight
    elif coin_type == 100:
        weight_difference = onehundred_bag_weight - bag_weight
        coins_changed = weight_difference / onehundred_coin_weight
    elif coin_type == 200:
        weight_difference = twohundred_bag_weight - bag_weight
        coins_changed = weight_difference / twohundred_coin_weight

    print("\nThe weight difference is", str(round(weight_difference)) + "g.")

    if coins_changed > 0:
        print("Add", round(coins_changed), "coins to the bag.\n")
        coins_value_added += coin_type
    else:
        print("Remove", round(coins_changed), "coins from the bag.\n")
        coins_value_removed += coin_type

    print("\n===========================\n")

print("There were", bag_count, "bags checked.")
print("There is", coins_value_added, "pence that needs to be added.")
print("There is", coins_value_removed, "pence that needs to be removed.")
```

Comment: you may find some answers here:<http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148994/money-bags-python/149088#149088>

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question.

Answer (score 3):

1) There's too much duplication. You can define a map, such as:

```
#This defines a mapping from coin value to a tuple (coin weight, monetary sack value)
coin_types = { 1: (3.56, 1), 2: (7.12, 1), ... }
```

Then, it's easy to calculate weights and amounts as such:

```
#This defines a mapping from coin value to a tuple (amount of coins in sack, sack weight)
coins_in_sack_by_type = {k: (v[1] / k, v[1] / k * v[2]) for (k, v) in coin_types.items()}
```

2) Now, most of your code in the main loop can be collapsed into:

```
weight_difference = coins_in_sack_by_type[coin_type][1] - sack_weight
coins_changed = weight_difference / coin_types[coin_type][0]
```

Comment: I'm a little unsure how to implement the second calculation of the first point. I understand the mapping of the coin types, but not the rest.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the particular part you're unsure about? I also missed a closing parentheses; just added it.

Comment: When I try to run the line `coins_in_sack_by_type = {k: (v[1] / k, v[1] / k * v[2]) for (k, v) in coin_types}`, the program terminates on an error that `'int' object is not iterable`, which is what I'm confused about - other than that I can generally grasp the rest of your feedback.

Comment: Apologies, I fixed that line - try again. If the feedback works for you, can you accept the answer?